# How can I open a TinyMce advimage plugin from outside of the editor?

Tags: tinymce

I want to launch the advimage plugin from outside of the TinyMCE editor (i.e. just a browse button on my page).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorry about that assumed the commercial image manager,

You can use

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="tinyMCE.get('IDOFYOURTEXTAREA').execCommand('mceAdvImage');">[Image]</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAdvImage');">[Image]</a>
```

This requires tinymce to be loaded somewhere though. Its not a full answer but at least wanted to replace my other one with a closer to correct answer.

Comment: that would be the commercial `mcimageimanager` plugin, not the `advimage` plugin that ships with tinymce